# Lstlisting does not break on long line containing only "*"

Tags: listings, line-breaking

When using the lstlisting environment, I can't get it to break on a long line which contains only the `*` character. This is my minimum working example. It produces a listing in which the text flows out of the listing's frame and does not produce correct line breaks. How do I fix this? I have tried different parameters in `\lstset`, but nothing seems to work. How do I tell the listing environment that it's okay to break on a `*`?

[image]

```
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{%
    breaklines=true,    
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    postbreak=\space,   
    tabsize=2,      
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, 
    showspaces=false,   
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true, 
    frame=single,       
    frameround=ffff,
    aboveskip=1.5em
}
\begin{lstlisting}
    **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** hello world
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The way text is broken in `listings` environment depends on the selected source code language. If you don't want to change the language setting, you can add the option `literate={*}{*\allowbreak}1` which replaces each `*` character by a version that allows a linebreak right after it.

Updated example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{%
    breaklines=true,    
    breakatwhitespace=false,
    postbreak=\space,   
    tabsize=2,      
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\footnotesize, 
    showspaces=false,   
    showstringspaces=false,
    extendedchars=true, 
    frame=single,       
    frameround=ffff,
    aboveskip=1.5em,
    literate={*}{*\allowbreak}1  % ADDED
}
\begin{lstlisting}
    **************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************** hello world
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]